# Prove that the expression has infinitely many solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

> Does $m = \dfrac{1}{72}\left(\sqrt{48r^2+1}+1\right)$ have infinitely many solutions in positive integers $(m,r)$?
>
> Does  $m = \dfrac{1}{18}\left(\sqrt{48r^2+1}-1\right)$ have infinitely many solutions in positive integers $(m,r)$ where $m \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$?

I wasn't sure how to prove that there are infinitely many solutions, but for both of them we need $48r^2$ to be one less than a perfect square. Thus we need $48r^2 = x^2-1$ and so $x^2-48r^2 = 1$, which has infinitely many solutions, but we also need $m$ to be an integer. How do we ensure that in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

The first has no solutions with positive integer $m$. However, the second case,

$$\begin{aligned}
m&=\dfrac{1}{18}\left(\sqrt{48r^2+1}-1\right)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{18}\left(x-1\right)\\
&\equiv {3\pmod{4}}
\end{aligned}$$

has infinitely many given by,

$$x= \frac{ (7+\sqrt{48})^{6k+3}+(7-\sqrt{48})^{6k+3}}{2}=1351,\; 9863382151,\; 72010600134783751\dots$$

$$r = \frac{ (7+\sqrt{48})^{6k+3}-(7-\sqrt{48})^{6k+3}}{2\sqrt{48}}=195,\; 1423656585,\; 10393834843080975\dots$$

Comment: How do you know the first has no solutions?

Comment: @Puzzled417: By inspection of the parametric solution to the Pell equation $x^2-48r^2=1$. Some users may give a short and rigorous proof for the non-existence of solutions for the first case.

Comment: That is, the [Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation), since even links to things you can look up yourself are useful.

Comment: How did you determine solutions to the second one?

Comment: @Puzzled417: Also by inspection and modular arithmetic. Sometimes the existence of solutions is easier to establish than its non-existence.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Is your argument for the non-existence of solutions of the first one heuristic?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: Yes. Nothing rigorous.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first equation, rearranging and squaring both sides we get $$72^2m^2-144m=48r^2,$$ which simplifies to $$108m^2-3m=3m(36m-1)=r^2.$$ Then $r^2=9k^2$ and $m=3n$ for some $k,n$, which yields $$n(108n-1)=k^2.$$ Since the factors of the LHS are coprime, both must be squares: say $n=y^2, 108n-1=x^2;$ therefore, $$x^2-108y^2=-1.$$ But $108$ is divisible by $4$, and [this excludes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html) the existence of any solution $(x,y)$, hence the original equation itself has no solutions.

Comment: How do we have $r^2 = 9km$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: We don't, that was a brainfart, sorry. See my edit, please.