# Solutions to $m = \dfrac{1}{18}\left(\sqrt{48r^2+1}-1\right)$

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

> Find all positive integer solution pairs $(m,r)$ to $m = \dfrac{1}{18}\left(\sqrt{48r^2+1}-1\right)$.

I thought about using Pell's equation, but that only tells us solutions such that $\sqrt{48r^2+1}$ is an integer. How do we deal with the $\dfrac{1}{18}$ and $-1$?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva There are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Expands to Pell equation $27 m^2-4r^2+3m = 0$. If you have a solution $m_n, r_n$ (such as $0, 0$), then a new solution can be generated with $m_{n+1} = 1351 m_n + 520 r_n + 75$ and $r_{n+1} = 3510 m_n + 1351 r_n + 195$

Comment: @MarcusStuhr Can you explain in more detail how this gets all the solutions?

Answer (score 1):

We can proceed similarly as in my answer to [your previous question,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885470/prove-that-the-expression-has-infinitely-many-solutions#) though this time it's to *find* the solutions. $(18m+1)^2=48r^2+1$ simplifies to $$3m(9m+1)=4r^2,$$so $r^2=9k^2$, $m=3n$ for some $k,n$. It follows that $$n(27n+1)=4k^2,$$ and since the factors of the LHS are coprime, both of them must be squares, say $n=y^2, 27n+1=x^2$. Therefore, $$x^2-27y^2=x^2-3(3y)^2=1.$$To find the fundamental solution $(x_0,y_0)$ we need to go through the convergents of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{3},$ but we're lucky because the $3y$ implies that the denominator of the "solving convergent" is a multiple of $3$: we quickly find the fifth convergent $\frac{26}{15}$ to provide us with $(x_0,y_0)=(26,5)$. As a consequence, $m=3\cdot5^2=75$ and $r=13\cdot15=195$ are solutions of your equation; defining $\{z_n\}$ to be the sequence of the indexes of the convergents that have a denominator divisible by $3$, all the other solutions $(m_n,r_n)$ can be deduced by the solutions of $x^2-3(3y)^2=1$, *i.e.*$$x_{n}=\frac{(2-\sqrt3)^{z_n}+(2+\sqrt3)^{z_n}}{2}$$and $$y_n=\frac{(2+\sqrt3)^{z_n}-(2-\sqrt3)^{z_n}}{6\sqrt3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not it is a Pell-type equation, it is solveable.

$$m = \frac{\sqrt{48r^2+1}-1}{18}
\implies 18m = \sqrt{48r^2+1}-1$$

$$(18m+1)^2=48r^2+1\implies 48r^2=(18m+1)^2-1
$$
$$r= \sqrt{\frac{(18m+1)^2-1}{48}}$$

Notice in the $(m,r)$ samples below that $m$ occurs only half the time and  as a [step] funtion of $n$.

$$m=\frac{8n-1}{2}\mp 0.5\quad n\in\mathbb{N}$$

$$
( 3,\pm 63)\space 
( 4,\pm 111)\qquad 
( 7,\pm 336)\space 
( 8,\pm 438)\qquad 
( 11,\pm 825)\space 
( 12,\pm 981)\\ 
( 15,\pm 1530)\space 
( 16,\pm 1740)\qquad 
( 19,\pm 2451)\space 
( 20,\pm 2715)\qquad 
( 23,\pm 3588)\space 
( 24,\pm 3906)\\ 
( 27,\pm 4941)\space 
( 28,\pm 5313)\qquad 
( 31,\pm 6510)\space 
( 32,\pm 6936)\qquad 
( 35,\pm 8295)\space 
( 36,\pm 8775)\\ 
( 39,\pm 10296)\space 
( 40,\pm 10830)\qquad 
( 43,\pm 12513)\space 
( 44,\pm 13101)\qquad 
( 47,\pm 14946)\space 
( 48,\pm 15588)$$

The values $(3,4,\space 7,8,\space 11,12,\space 15,16,\space 19,20,\space 23,24,...)$ are part of series
[A014601](https://oeis.org/A014601).